# conceptually, how to use NLP to predict a numeric output

Tags: neural-networks, natural-language, lstm, feature-engineering

suppose I'm trying to use medical notes to predict the cost of medical service.  For example, a patient will call in, tell the operator how they feel, their diagnosis, etc etc, and the operator will take down all the notes.  Over time, as the patient visits the doctor, gets medication, treatment, they would incur the final cost of the service.
My job is to predict that final cost (as close as possible) based on the initial notes.

I'm familiar with how to do standard EDA on the text; word frequency, sentiment, n-grams etc etc, but I dont know how that translates to a numerical output.  As an analogy, if this was a linear regression,  it's intuitive to me in the sense of each variable having a beta and I can say "for each x1 increase, y will increase by whatever %..."

But for text, how does it work?  Should the approach to find keywords that result in a certain value?  i,e, there should be a relationship between the word "cancer" and cost, etc?

Trying to wrap my head around this and get a sense of where to start and what to be look for.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the regression the same way as you do the classification. You have some input features (either hand-crafted: *n*-grams, word frequencies; or from a neural network) and then, instead of a classifier, you do regression. By that I mean, that you do a linear projection into a scalar and compute the loss as a mean square error and propagate it back to the model (or update the model in a different way if it is not a neural network).

Sometimes, it is better to cast the problem as a classification problem (presumably because classification provides stronger training signal than regression). In that case, you can split the target values into several buckets—some reasonable intervals that evenly cover the target values. You can then either take the most probable interval or estimate the target values as an expected value from the model: $\sum_I p_I c_I$ where $c_I$ is the center of the interval $I$ and $p_I$ is the probability assigned to interval $I$ by the model.